# Error creating bean (is edite)

Tags: spring, hibernate, java

Суть проблемы:

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Air] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: chpt.db.model.Students] with root cause
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: chpt.db.model.Students

application-Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="chpt"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="chpt.db.model"/>

    <!-- import the dataSource definition  <import resource="applicationContext-dataSource.xml"/>-->
    <import resource="applicationContext-dataSource.xml"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>

                <!-- <value>/chpt/db/hibernate-mapping.hbm.xml</value> -->
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>chpt.db.model.Airport</value>
                <value>chpt.db.model.Flight</value>
                <value>chpt.db.model.Movement_flights</value>
                <value>chpt.db.model.Passenger</value>
                <value>chpt.db.model.Plane</value>
                <value>chpt.db.model.Students</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
                hibernate.show_sql=true
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="transactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <bean class="chpt.Controller.IndexController" id="dbUtil"/>
</beans>
```

DbUtil.java

```
package chpt.db;

import java.util.*;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import chpt.db.model.*;

//import chpt.db.model.*;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class DBUtil
{
    Configuration config;

    private SessionFactory sf;
    private Session session;

    @Autowired
    public DBUtil(SessionFactory sessionFactory) 
    {
        sf = sessionFactory;
        session =  sf.openSession();
    }

    public void save(Object obj)
    {
        session.beginTransaction(); 
        session.clear();
        session.save(obj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();  
    }   
    public void update(Object obj)
    {
        session.beginTransaction(); 
        session.clear();
        session.update(obj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();  
    }   
    public void dell(Object obj)
    {
        session.beginTransaction(); 
        session.clear();
        session.delete(obj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();      
    }

    public List<Students> getStudents(){
        return session.createQuery("from chpt.db.model.Students").list();
    }
```

IndexController.java

```
package chpt.Controller;

import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import chpt.db.*;
import chpt.elements.TableHtml;
import chpt.db.model.*;
import chpt.elements.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index.htm")
public class IndexController
{   
    ModelAndView modelAndView;

    private final DBUtil dbUtil;

    TableHtml adapterManager;

    String namePage;
    String attributeTabelName;

    @Autowired
    public IndexController(DBUtil dbUtil)
    {        
        this.dbUtil = dbUtil;

        adapterManager = null;

        namePage = "index"; 
        attributeTabelName = "tabel";       
    }

        @RequestMapping(params="Lab3", method=RequestMethod.GET)
protected void viewStudents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
    List<Students> data = dbUtil.getStudents();
    adapterManager = new TableStudents(data);
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(adapterManager.CreateView());  
}
}
```

Students.java

```
package chpt.db.model;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import chpt.db.Tabels;

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Students extends chpt.db.AbstractTableModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    int id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    String first_name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    String last_name;
    @Column(name = "birthday")
    Date birthday;
    @Column(name = "faculty")
    int faculty;

    public Students(Tabels typeTabel) {
        typeTabel = Tabels.Students;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public int getFaculty() {
        return faculty;
    }

    public void setFaculty(int facult) {
        this.faculty = facult;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAll(Object[] obj) throws ParseException {
        id = Integer.parseInt((String) obj[0]);

    }

}
```

Не знаю, что делать, ибо бы не постил сюда. Все пути прописаны правильно, несколько дней не могу разобраться с этой проблемой.

Comment: Гениальный вопрос

Comment: Почему то @Autowired не инициализирует DbUtil для Students ну и по цепочке...
Как это понятно с ошибки.
Уважаемый Barmaley! Если бы я знал что не так, я бы сюда не писал. Так что уж извините, на блюдичке не могу преподнести.

Comment: @smail2133 вы бы для начала:

   1) отформатировали код

   2) отделили "зерна от плевел", то есть хотя бы сформулировали вопрос, а именно написали что не работает то? Вы сами то читали свой вопрос?

   3) Вопрос как раз должен быть "на блюдечке" - четкий, ясный. У вас и вопроса то нет - здесь не "Битва Экстрасенсов" - нет людей способных угадать чего вы хотели.

Comment: @smail2133: и правда, потрудитесь выкинуть из вопроса всё ненужное. У вас одно только сообщение об ошибке занимает пол-экрана, прочитайте его сами и оставьте только нужную часть. Создайте мини-проект, воспроизводящий проблему. Уберите все поля из базы данных, кроме одного. Уберите геттеры и сеттеры, они точно нерелевантны.

Если вы этого не сделаете, за вас это придётся делать нам, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос. А мы точно так же ленивы, как и вы, может даже больше -- проблема-то у вас.

Comment: Удалил свой ответ, т.к. он уже не соответствует вопросу. Присоединяюсь к негодующим выше. Искать проблему за вас, да еще и при смене симптомов, крайне сложно.

Comment: спасибо и на этом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос содержится в сообщении об ошибке, которое вы привели:

> org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: chpt.db.model.Students

Видимо, вы не смогли перевести это сообщение. Здесь написано, что для класса `chpt.db.model.Students` нет конструктора по умолчанию (иными словами конструктора без аргументов).

Обычно этот конструктор создаётся компилятором (неявно и автоматически), но только тогда когда вы не объявили его (или любой другой конструктор) самостоятельно. В вашем случае в классе `Students` уже есть конструктор:

```
public Students(Tabels typeTabel) {
    typeTabel = Tabels.Students;
}
```

Поэтому варианта два -- либо добавить конструктор без аргументов, либо убрать этот (чтобы компилятор создал конструктор по умолчанию для вас).

(Тег `spring`, а также листинги файлов `application-Context.xml`, `DbUtil.java` и `IndexController.java` можно убрать из вопроса, т.к. они не имеют к нему отношения. В листинге файла `Students.java` геттеры и сеттеры тоже можно опустить, чтобы сделать вопрос более коротким и ясным.)